# Need help with this ice cream logic puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Disclaimer! I'm not looking for the answer, so no need to solve it. Just some help.

In this website [here](https://www.ahapuzzles.com/logic/logic-puzzles/ice-cream-for-snack/) I have tried many times to no avail. I don't know what I am getting mixed up on. So far I have this
[image]

Description:

> Five children have decided to have an ice cream for a snack. Each child has bought a cone with two different flavors at a different time than the others. With the help of the clues, could you figure out at what time each child has eaten his ice cream and its flavors?

Clues:

> 1. Just one child, George, has bought an ice cream with two fruits flavors. He has bought it before Steven but one hour after Luc.
> 2. Philip has chosen either watermelon or vanilla as first flavors and coconut or chocolate as second.
> 3. One child has chosen hazelnut as first flavor and chocolate as second. He has bought his ice cream one hour before than Steven.
> 4. The child who has bought his ice cream at 4.00 pm, has chosen pistachio as second flavor but neither vanilla or watermelon as first.
> 5. Steven has chosen strawberry as second flavor. The child, who has bought his ice cream at 6.00 pm has chosen coconut flavor.
> 6. None of the ice creams have been chosen together with chocolate and strawberry.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that you've missed out on right away. The first is something you can deduce before you even read the first clue:

> "Each child has bought a cone with two different flavors" - the bottom square shows the relationship between first and second flavors. You can immediately rule out chocolate-chocolate, etc.

Then from the first clue:

> You can make some deductions about when Luc could have bought ice cream. Also, since George bought ice cream before Steven, 5 PM is not an option for Steven.

One additional meta hint - having an entire section empty (in this case the 1st flavor vs 2nd flavor section) indicates that you should go back through the information you've been given and double-check what deductions can be made for that section.

Comment: I think there are two solutions for this particular puzzle? Philip and Steven's first flavor can be either Vanilla or Watermelon. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, so having the reverse of 1st flavor + 2nd flavor is also not allowed I guess

Comment: @justhalf Steven has Strawberry as his second flavor, and George is the only one with two fruit flavors. So Steven can't have Watermelon as his first flavor. Not sure what you mean about the reverse of 1st flavor + 2nd flavor.

Comment: Ahh, so that's the restriction, thanks. Because Steven having Watermelon as first would result in Watermelon+Strawberry for him and Strawberry+Watermelon for Philip, which I thought was the reason for disallowing it. But yeah, I missed the uniqueness condition on the two fruit flavors.

Answer (score 0):

> One child has chosen hazelnut as first flavor and chocolate as second

This directly translates to a green check mark in the bottom part that you didn't mark yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another immediate deduction you can make is that, when you have a checkmark, everything you know about one, you know about the other.

Example: Since

- Steven has strawberry for his second flavor
- The person with strawberry for second isn't 6:00
- Thf Steven isn't 6:00.